# Is pemission of slave's family necessary for marriage?

Tags: nikah, slavery

> And whoever among you cannot [find] the means to marry free, believing
> women, then [he may marry] from those whom your right hands possess of
> believing slave girls. And Allah is most knowing about your faith. You
> [believers] are of one another. **So marry them with the permission of
> their people** and give them their due compensation according to what
> is acceptable. [They should be] chaste, neither [of] those who commit
> unlawful intercourse randomly nor those who take [secret] lovers. But
> once they are sheltered in marriage, if they should commit adultery,
> then for them is half the punishment for free [unmarried] women. This
> [allowance] is for him among you who fears sin, but to be patient is
> better for you. And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.Quran 4:25

What is the meaning of part in bold. Does it mean get permission of parents of slave girl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Their people" in this verse means "their masters." It is obligatory to have the permission of the master of a slave before marrying her.

Tabari says:

> ⟪with the permission of their people⟫ i.e. with the permission of their masters i.e. when they tell you to marry them and approve it

Zajjaj says:

> ⟪So, marry them with the permission of their people⟫ i.e. Allah commands them to be married with the permission of their masters.

Zamakhshari says:

> ⟪with the permission of their people⟫ is a condition to take permission from their masters when marrying them.

The word Ahl (people) is much broader than "family."

Answer (score 1):

It means the permission of the owner of the slave as stated in some other translations:

> فانكحوهن بإذن أهلهن
>
> So, marry them with the permission of their masters
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:25](https://quran.com/4/25?translations=84)</sup>

The guardian of a slave for the purpose of marriage is her owner, not anyone else, as evident from the Quran, Sunnah and Ijma'.

> وأنكحوا ... الصالحين من عبادكم وإمائكم
>
> Arrange the marriage of ... the capable from among your bondmen and bondwomen
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:32](https://quran.com/24/32?translations=84)</sup>

> أيما عبد تزوج بغير إذن سيده فهو عاهر
>
> Whichever slave gets married without the permission of his owner, then he is a fornicator.
>
> <sup>—  [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2078), [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1111)</sup>

> الأمة لا ولاية لأبيها عليها، وإنما وليها سيدها. بغير خلاف علمناه
>
> The father of a slave woman does not have guardianship over her, rather her guardian is her owner. There is no disagreement on this according to our knowledge.
>
> <sup>— [al-Mughni](https://shamela.ws/book/6910/4738)</sup>